# Is there a Wordpress gallery plugin that connects to an image folder on Google Drive?

Tags: wordpress, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive that I'm allowing various other community users to upload files to.  We have multiple folders with each folder containing a number of photo's of whatever event that folder represents. I'm after a Wordpress plugin that scans a selected top-level folder on Google Drive and dynamically creates the gallery categories and images from the folder contents.

I'm aiming to have this work so that if a user creates a new folder and dumps some photos in it, a new gallery category will appear as if by magic on my Wordpress site filled with the photos the user put in the folder.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: http://www.wordpress.stackexchange.com/ use this if your question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Asking for recomendations is off-topic here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the Google Drive plugin for WordPress http://codecanyon.net/item/useyourdrive-google-drive-plugin-for-wordpress/6219776. It does not reupload the Google Drive contents to your server – instead, the content is loaded every time a user accesses the site. I am using it now and it works well concerning the functions, yet is sometimes kind of slow.

Developers description: "This plugin will help you to easily integrate Google Drive into your WordPress website or blog. Use-your-Drive allows you to view, download, delete, rename files & folders directly from a WordPress page. You can use Use-your-Drive as a filebrowser, gallery, audio- or video-player!".